# Set up a matlab eclipse interface

Tags: android, eclipse, sockets, matlab

Could we write an android client to ask for some data from Matlab output and then write the server part in matlab that sends the information to eclipse?

How can we do this? Can we do this through wireless connection? Or use internet to connect to computers together to do this?

Do you have any example on how we could do this? I'm totally new to socket programming and Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make an android client talks to MatLab first you will need to open a socket.
That will be made like you would do with java in the android application.
An example of socket communication with matlab is seen in here (it uses java):
http://iheartmatlab.blogspot.com.br/2008/08/tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab.html

You can use the same object in android to make a socket comunication (Using java.net.socket): http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html

I just do not understand what you want to do with eclipse.